# My overlay pushes the rest of the page down rather than appearing on top

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

I want a `<div>` to appear over the current screen when the user clicks on an image whilst darkening the background out behind the overlay. However rather than the `<div>` appearing just over the top of the screen in the current position, it pushes everything in the background beneath it.

**Screenshot before Overlay:**
[image: Before the overlay has been applied]

**Screen after Overlay has been applied (you can see it pushes the other elements beneath):**
[image: After overlay]

On a side note, is there a way in which just by clicking in the darkened out background (out of the overlay) it closes the overlay down?

**HTML:**

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <section id="grid" class="clearfix">
            <div class="cf show-grid">
                <div class="row">
                <!-- Start Overlay -->
                <div id="overlay"></div>
                <!-- End Overlay -->
                <!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
                <div id="specialBox">
                <button onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Close Overlay</button>
                </div>
                <!-- End Special Centered Box -->
                <!-- Start Normal Page Content -->
                <div id="wrapper">
                <button onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Apply Overlay</button>
               </div>
               <!-- End Normal Page Content -->

               <div class="grid-2 dashboardIcons">
                   <h3 class="fontAmaticH1">Stress & Anxiety</h3>
                       <a href="stess-anxiety.php"><img src="images/stress.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-2 dashboardIcons">
                    <h3 class="fontAmaticH1">Mindfulness</h3>
                       <a class="cursor" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()"><img src="images/mindfulness.jpg"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="grid-2 dashboardIcons">
                     <h3 class="fontAmaticH1">Exam Preperation</h3>
                        <a href="exam-prep.php"><img src="images/examPrep.jpg"></a>
               </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*Practising the overlays for modules */
div#overlay {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
div#specialBox {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
    width: 500px; 
    height: 300px;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
div#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left:24px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
/* This is for the page overloays within the module pages */
function toggleOverlay(){
  var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
    overlay.style.opacity = .8;
    if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        specialBox.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

For info: I am using [Foldy Grids](https://github.com/davatron5000/Foldy960) to ensure my divs are all responsive etc.

Comment: can you share the remaining html structure? how is the content that is pushed down styled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `div#specialBox` try this:

```css
position: fixed;
top: 150px;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%); /* this will place it in the center */
```

And delete this *(also for `div#specialBox`)*:

```css
position: relative;
margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
```

While `div#specialBox` has [`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) then the block will be in "main flow" and push the rest page down. Position `fixed` and `absolute` *"remove"* the block from this flow.

Comment: So I tried to add those 4 lines into the styling for `div#specialBox` and then remove those 2 lines you suggested however nothing seems to have changed. The overlay still doesn't appear on top of the current screen without pushing all the content beneath?

Comment: Maybe your styles were cached? This is strange if nothing changed. What styles for element do you see in DevTools?

Comment: Much appreciated, it worked perfectly, I just had to clear the cache, it's quite annoying that chrome caches automatically :) Side note - Is there somethingI can add into the CSS to make the overlay stick and when I scroll, stop the background from scrolling?

Comment: You need to add `overflow: hidden;` for `body` when `#specialBox` is opened. Like `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";` and `document.body.style.overflow = "auto";`

Comment: Would this be in the JavaScript? So, just apply that to the body of `#specialBox` ?

Comment: yes, this should be in js, right after `specialBox.style.display = "none";` and `specialBox.style.display = "block";`, depends on state.